# jQuery Datepicker - do not highlight today

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jQuery Datepicker (jQuery 1.11.3 / jQuery UI 1.11.4 > I'm bound to these versions and can not alter or change them in any way).

Out of the box, jQuery Datepicker highlights today the following way:

```
    <td class="ui-datepicker-days-cell-over ui-datepicker-current-day ui-datepicker-today"> <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#" tabindex="144">26</a> </td>
```

Now I want to get rid of the ui-state-highlight class in order to prevent this behaviour.

I searched for numerous hints on the web, all of which are more or less the same like this (including timeouts, .find() etc.):

```
beforeShow:
function (textbox, instance) {
setTimeout(
function () {
$(
"#ui-datepicker-div td.ui-datepicker-today a.ui-state-highlight").removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
}, 300
);
//settimeout function end
}
```

However all of these solutions are not working.

Has anyone a working solution to this problem?

Comment: Add some CSS rules that cancel the highlighting?

Comment: no this is not a solution because then you can not select (=highlight) "today" anymore. I already tried that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make sure the jquery-ui doesn't add the class after showing the `datepicker` you can run this code after rendering the datepicker.

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').datepicker({
   //options
})
.find('a.ui-state-highlight')
.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

Comment: PURE GENIUS!!!!! Thank you very much! This is the only solution on the interwebs without any shady hacks, setTimeouts or rendering flicks and it works flawlessy! Once again thank you. Since a lot of ppl are looking for this functionality I would love this answer to become more popular.

Answer (score 2):

Another faster approach: Comment out the following line in **jquery-ui-[version].custom.css**

```
/ ** ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {} */
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work I had to remove two classes, and give some timeout, this is my solution:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
                    $( "#embeded_calendar" ).datepicker().find('.ui-stateactive').removeClass('ui-state-active');
                    $( "#embeded_calendar" ).datepicker().find('.ui-datepicker-today').removeClass('ui-datepicker-today');
             },10)
```